# iOS Identifying views in ObjC and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

What is the best practice to identify views in iOS?
For instance, you could have a lot of views that aren't worth subclassing because you need to work with just one subview in those views.

I like to use view tags, and for easy identification I would do like so for ObjC:

```
enum {
    kViewTagSomeButton = 10,
    kViewTagSomeOtherButton,
}
```

But to do this in Swift, this becomes quite verbose:

```
enum ViewTag: Int {
    case SomeButton = 10, SomeOtherButton, ...
}

if view.tag == ViewTag.SomeButton.rawValue {
    // Do something
}
```

Or should I use a completely different approach?

**Edited**
Changed the whole question to a more appropriate context

Comment: Note that "What is the best way" will likely get your question closed as primarily opinion-based. You should reword at least the ending sentence with the actual problem you have.

Comment: Do you have outlets, properties, or ivars for the text fields?

Comment: Yeah.. I've noticed that. Obviously, when most people ask for "the best way", they don't really mean "What is the best way that the god of programming would approve of no matter what" but "What is the best practice" or "What is Apple approved", but people close those questions. I sometimes don't understand this community..

Comment: You wrote *"I read using tags are faster for identification"*. Faster than what?

Comment: @rmaddy See updated question

Comment: I guess I started using enums after reading the quoted document, but remembered it the wrong way. Not sure at this point if checking for the tag is better than checking the address.

Comment: Why do you have a comment below `if (textField == self.userNameField)` stating "This is slower". Slower than what? It doesn't get any faster than comparing two pointers for equality.

Comment: BTW - the performance difference in any of these approaches is so trivial. You are really wasting a lot of time on a non-issue.

Comment: @rmaddy Thought in a very complex view hierarchy, it could affect performance. I still like the idea of using tags though, in cases where you're using a table view cell without subclassing it or you just want to refer to a view you'll need to reference only a few times. I thought setting a property for those views were wasteful. Self-taught with no CS fundamentals so I'm trying to learn...

Comment: Using tags is fragile and error-prone.